# How can I find out which object has a file open in Java?

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

I need to find out **which object** in my Java app has a file open. This is for debugging, so tools or utilities are welcome.

If finding **which object** is too specific, which **class** would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That could be tricky. You could start by using a profiler, like [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) (free) or [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) (not free) to inspect [java.io.File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) objects in memory. If you can find one with the path you're interested in, that might point you in the right direction. The problem is that a File object doesn't necessarily have to exist for an app to still have the file open.

Your next step might be to set breakpoints in both [FileInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and [FileOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) (unless you know whether the file is being read or written to), attach a debugger, and watch for your file to be opened by one of those. But of course, there are other ways of opening files as well. You might also need to stake out things like [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and [URL.openConnection()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29), for example.

Your last resort might be to try out an omniscient debugger, like [ODB](http://www.lambdacs.com/debugger/) or [TOD](http://pleiad.dcc.uchile.cl/tod/). I only have limited experience with them, but they claim to "know everything". You'll just have to figure out how to ask the right question.

Comment: this is the path id choose to investigate - i dont have the time to do so at the moment due to work priorities however am marking it as correct

Answer (score 4):

The following is Windows and IntelliJ specific, though it is likely similar for other operating systems and IDEs.

Additionally it relies on JDK internals, the following has been written for JDK 11.

---

1. Find out the `handle` of the file. For this you can use the Windows Sysinternals [Handle tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) (see also [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/a/1980)):

   ```
   .\handle64.exe -p java
   ```
2. In the output search for the relevant file, e.g.:

   ```
   D7C: File          C:\Users\Someone\myfile.txt
   ```

   (Note: Most terminals provide a search function, for `cmd.exe` it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>; for [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/) it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.)
   The value before the colon is important (in this example `D7C`), note it down.
3. In IntelliJ pause execution with the debugger.
4. Open the [Memory tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyze-objects-in-the-jvm-heap.html)
5. Search for `java.io.FileDescriptor`
6. Right-click the result and select "Show Instances"
7. As condition enter `handle == 0xhandle`, with **handle** being the value you noted down in step 2 (in this example `handle == 0xD7C`).
   (Note: Under Unix you might have to compare `fd ==` instead.)
   ➔ You should see a single result
8. Right-click the result and select "Show Referring Objects..."
9. On the results you can then continue selecting "Show Referring Objects..." until you found the relevant result (the reference in `FileCleanable` can most likely be ignored)

This won't always answer which caller forgot to close the file, but it might give a hint. You can then for example set further breakpoints in the relevant classes to find out who opened the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use AspectJ and intercept calls to various flavors of opening file streams.  Use an around aspect.  Note this can only tell you which object opens the stream, but obviously the object can pass around references to the stream, so ...

Comment: -1 At least as I read it, this is a debugging question, not a design question.

Comment: Sorry to reply to your old comment, @EdStaub, but alphazero was implying to use the aspect as a **debugging** tool. He did not suggest to change the application design. FYI, I often use aspects for debugging purposes and just deactivate them if I do not need them anymore. This is a powerful tool and often the better alternative to step-debugging through an application.